# Detecting Terminal Tabstop Settings

Tags: terminal, tabs

I'm writing a small program that needs to wrap text to produce multi column output on a terminal screen.  This is fairly straightforward, except for having to account for hard tabs, which I cannot do without knowing what the tab stop settings are.  Is there a way to query for tab stop settings?  On OSX the `tabs` command appears to set tabs, but doesn't seem to report them.  I can possibly parse `infocmp` output for the `it` value, but that seems to be just the default tab width, which may or may not line up with the full set of tab stops.

Is there a canonical way of pulling the tab stop settings on unix-like terminals?  On Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`tabs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/tabs.html) program uses data from the terminal database, to tell the terminal what tab-stops to use.

The computer does not know about the tab-stops: using `stty` you can set the terminal driver to use hard-tabs or soft (the usual expansion of 8 columns per tab stop).  Whether you set hard/soft tabs, most applications on the system will assume 8, anyway.

The terminal database does not provide a standard way to determine *what* the tab-stops are set to.  For the widely-used VT100 emulations in xterm, etc., it is *possible* to determine this information by using the cursor-position report.  Someone could write an application that wrote tabs, used the cursor-report to see where the cursor ended up, and compute the tab-stops.  (The [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program uses the cursor-position report to determine the screen size).

ncurses's terminal database provides `u6` capabilities which attempt to describe cursor-position reports, but for practical purposes only the VT100-style reports are supported.